# TypeError when calling a generic callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a generic stateful widget to display radio buttons. I have got it working, but every time I choose a different radio and the onChanged function gets called, I get the following error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(TaskType) => void' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => void)?'
```

The error does not stop the widget from working, but I would still like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Widget Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DialogRadio<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<T, String> choices;
  final T? initialSelected;
  final void Function(T?)? onChanged;

  const DialogRadio({
    Key? key,
    required this.choices,
    this.initialSelected,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DialogRadioState<T> createState() => _DialogRadioState<T>();
}

class _DialogRadioState<T> extends State<DialogRadio> {
  T? _selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selected = widget.initialSelected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: widget.choices.entries.map(
        (_entry) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              Radio<T>(
                value: _entry.key,
                groupValue: _selected,
                onChanged: (_value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _selected = _value;
                    },
                  );
                  widget.onChanged?.call(_value);
                },
              ),
              Text(_entry.value),
            ],
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Full Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(TaskType) => void' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => void)?'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _DialogRadioState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:salt/components/dialog_radio.dart:53:26)
#1      _RadioState._handleChanged (package:flutter/src/material/radio.dart:371:24)
#2      ToggleableStateMixin._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/toggleable.dart:229:19)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
#14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
#15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)


══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(TaskType) => void' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => void)?'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _DialogRadioState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:salt/components/dialog_radio.dart:53:26)
#1      _RadioState._handleChanged (package:flutter/src/material/radio.dart:371:24)
#2      ToggleableStateMixin._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/toggleable.dart:229:19)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
#14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
#15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)


══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(TaskType) => void' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => void)?'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _DialogRadioState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:salt/components/dialog_radio.dart:53:26)
#1      _RadioState._handleChanged (package:flutter/src/material/radio.dart:371:24)
#2      ToggleableStateMixin._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/toggleable.dart:229:19)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
#14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
#15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#bcf62
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: I got it. I missed the generic when extending the state.

```class _DialogRadioState<T> extends State<DialogRadio<T>>```